# mySQL unique parts from two tables linked by customer number

Tags: mysql

I don't know if this is possible. I have two tables - quotation_items and order_items. Both tables have a part_no field.

The quotation_items links to a table quotations which has a field cust_id. The order_items links to orders which also has a field cust_id.

What I am looking to do is to build a query (which will become a view) of UNIQUE part numbers, ie no replication even if they are in both tables based on a cust_id.

I know I could build an array with PHP but this way I could use a datatable to show the results.

Comment: show the tables with sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the base query that you want:

```
select distinct cust_id, part_no
from (select cust_id, part_no
      from quotation_items qi
      union all
      select cust_id, part_no
      from order_items
     ) t
```

Unfortunately, you cannot put this into a view in MySQL, because it has a subquery in the `from` clause.  In order to put this in a view, you may need to use two views, one for the inner query one for the outer one.

EDIT:

You can put this into a view, by doing:

```
select cust_id, part_no
from quotation_items qi
union
select cust_id, part_no
from order_items;
```

This uses `union` to remove the duplicates.